# iOS Video thumbail frames scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, video

I want to develop a app where to add music to a video. So I want to display the video frames in a time and also when we move the timeline then video preview should display in player(Same as iOS native video frames displayed in gallery).

So, how can I create the scroll for the frames and display the preview of video. Is there any open source library that can display ?